# Showing that a random variable has bounded second moment

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normed-spaces

Given random variables $X, Y, Z$, with $\mathbb{E}X^2 < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}Z^2 < \infty$. If we have

\begin{equation}\mathbb{E} \lvert  X - Y \rvert ^2 < \mathbb{E}\lvert Z \rvert^2,\end{equation}

then what can we say about the second moment of $Y$? Is it possible to deduce that $\mathbb{E}Y^2 < \infty$ also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after submitting my question, the solution came to me:

Starting from $\mathbb{E}\lvert X-Y \rvert^2  < \infty$, we have
\begin{aligned}
\lvert (\mathbb{E}\lvert X \rvert^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (\mathbb{E}\lvert Y \rvert^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \rvert < \infty
\end{aligned}
which implies
\begin{equation}
-\infty < (\mathbb{E}\lvert X \rvert^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (\mathbb{E}\lvert Y \rvert^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
and it follows that $\mathbb{E}Y^2 < \infty$.

Comment: I think you just want to use the triangular inequality for the $L^2$ norm: $\lVert Y\rVert_2 \leq \lVert X-Y\rVert_2 + \lVert X\rVert_2 < \infty$

Comment: @charlus yes, that's much simpler than my solution.